# Firebase(with Kotlin) ArrayList Casting Error

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a basic shopping app with Kotlin. And I'm using Firebase to upload and retrieve "bought products" ArrayList. I'm uploading it like this:

```
 val productId = productList.get(position).id
 boughtProductArray.add(productId)
 document.update("boughtItems",boughtProductArray)
```

And retrieving like this:

```
        db.collection("gamevalues").document(userId).addSnapshotListener{snapshot, error->
        if(error!=null){
            Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.context,error.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }else{
            if(snapshot!=null && snapshot.exists()){
                boughtProductArray = snapshot.get("boughtItems") as ArrayList<Int>
                for (i in boughtProductArray){
                    println(i)
                }

            }
            else{
                println("Error")
            }

        }

    }
```

But when I do this, app instantly crashes and gives an error:

```
2022-08-23 23:02:09.580 19808-19808/com.mycompany.shoppingapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.mycompany.shoppingapp, PID: 19808
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

And it points this line:

```
for (i in boughtProductArray){
```

[image: This is my database structure]

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: I've added a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers in your `boughtItems` array are of type Long, and **not** Int. Since between these two classes, there is no inheritance relationship, the casting is not possible, hence that error. To solve this, please change the of the list from Int to Long:

```
boughtProductArray = snapshot.get("boughtItems") as ArrayList<Long>
//
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But why the numbers in boughtItems is Long? I just store product id's(integers like 1,2,3) Should I initialize product id as an integer even if it is just a number?

Comment: In order to be able to store large numbers, the type should be Long and not Int. So always treat them al Long numbers and not Int.

Answer (score 0):

change ArrayList to long and it should work

Comment: Which ArrayList should I change? And how the code should look like? Can you give me an example?